# Can't create CAA record for subdomain on AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, lets-encrypt

I have a public hosted zone at AWS Route 53. Just for the simplicity let's call the domain "foo.com". Which I bought a certificate for from Comodo.

I have a CNAME type record for the subdomain "bar.foo.com". In order to renew the Let’s Encrypt certificate for the "bar.foo.com subdomain I need  to add a CAA record.

I'm getting the following error message if I try to add the CAA record for the subdomain.

```
Name: bar.foo.com | Type: CAA | Value: 0 issue "letsencrypt.org"
```

Error message:

> RRSet of type CAA with DNS name bar.foo.com. is not permitted because
>   a conflicting RRSet of type CNAME with the same DNS name already
>   exists in zone foo.com.

Here a screenshot from the AWS console:
[image]

Comment: The error means you already have a `CNAME` record on same label `bar.foo.com` and by definition if you have a `CNAME` record on some label you can not have any other record types for the same label.

Answer (score 8):

I got it working! I entered a second line in the CAA record of "foo.com"

```
0 issue "letsencrypt.org"
```

I'm not sure if that is the right thing to do but it works.

[image]

Comment: If you want to preserve the CNAME record and if it does not bother you that you allow Let's encrypt to make certificates for your root domain, than this solution is the only one that will work in your case and in my opinion it's perfectly fine.

Comment: Alternately, since this record targets another value from the same hosted zone, change the `CNAME` to an `A` record with `Alias` set to `Yes` and then use the same target value as before.  This would allow other records to coexist in a way `CNAME` doesn't (and shouldn't).

Comment: This totally saved me! Can't believe it's not in AWS docs.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Use an A record (or enable Route53’s alias), instead of a CNAME.

Patrick mentioned it in the comments above, but the issue is actually that AWS adheres to the DNS RFC 1912, specifically section 2.4:

> A CNAME record is not allowed to coexist with any other data.

AWS mentioned it in their [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html#CNAMEFormat) too:

> […] if you create a CNAME record for a subdomain, you cannot create any other records for that subdomain

To work around this, you’ll need to create a subdomain record that is NOT a CNAME. You can move the CAA record to the apex, but you’ll need to add all CA’s you’re using too. Ex: [AWS’s ACM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/setup-caa.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a CAA record and a CNAME record that have the same name:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/ResourceRecordTypes.html#CAAFormat